# PWA occasionally not displaying in Facebook in-app browser on Android

Tags: android, angular, facebook, progressive-web-apps

I have an `Angular 4` website that is using Service workers to cache static files to improve performance. I've found that the Facebook app on Android has issues displaying the site.

I tried it on a new device and the site seems to work on Facebook until I open it manually in Chrome. After that, it displays the odd behavior of sometimes rendering correctly and then other times just displaying a blank white page with only the title set correctly.

Has anyone had issues like this previously? I haven't found any relevant bug reports online and I wonder what might be the problem here. The url of the page in question is: [www.saillogapp.com/coaches](https://www.saillogapp.com/coaches)

Steps to reproduce:

1) Send the link to yourself in Messenger

2) Open it a couple of times by clicking on the link (make sure it opens in the in-app browser)

3) Try a couple of times: it will fail after three or so reopens.

4) Check that the site loads correctly in Chrome

I tried checking in Android `logcat`, but there are no visible errors from the Facebook app.

Comment: Instead of using `logcat` to debug, I'd recommend following the steps at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ and check to see what errors are logged in the DevTools for the embedded instance of Chrome that Facebook is using.

Comment: @JeffPosnick I tried it now with DevTools but it doesn't recognise the embedded WebView inside Facebook. It doesn't show up in open tabs, nor does it log any errors to the console. Any other ideas maybe?